# Is it possible to mix several declarations/initializations?

Tags: c, initialization, declaration

I use only C99, and, yesterday, I heard that it was impossible to mix several declarations and initializations in ANSI C. Thus, codes like this :

```
unsigned x = 42, y = 21;
double e = 3.14;
```

Would be, with gcc' `-pedantic` flag :

```
unsigned x, y;
double e;

x = 42, y = 21;
e = 3.14;
```

I'm surprised, because I didn't find any information about that in C89 draft, and a code like this works fine...

```
unsigned x = 42, y = 21;
double e = 3.14;
```

Sorry, it seems to be a trivial question, but I did some research, and nothing told me about this rule...
Is it true ?

Comment: I get no error from `c99 -Wall -pedantic`.

Comment: Me too. But he told me that with -ansi -pedantic -pedantic-errors he had some errors.

Comment: @Lucas Pesenti Who told you that ?

Comment: @LucasPesenti "Some errors"? Wow. Good for you. Will you keep them secret, or will you integrate them in your answer in order to let us know about them?

Comment: Sorry, he didn't tell me those errors. I will ask him... I thought that the draft would be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An initialization is a part of declaration, so you can do initialization in a declaration in both C89/C99:

```
/* Valid in C89 and C99. There are no statement, only declarations */
unsigned x = 42, y = 21;
double e = 3.14;
```

What you cannot do is to mix statements and declarations in C89:

```
/* Not valid in C89, valid in C99: mixing declarations and statements */
unsigned x, y;
x = 42, y = 21;

double e;
e = 3.14;
```

Comment: Ok, so it seems to be valid. Thanks, I gonna think about that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm using your first syntax with `-pedantic` flag and it works well, without any warning.
As far as I know, you can't mix your code like this:

```
int i;
i = 2;
int j;
j = 2;
```

This is because, in C semantic, every program is a block and a block is a couple [declarations, commands]. But declaration include initialization of variables as well.

Every time you open a new block, for example with a while or an if, you'll have a second block, and again you can have a declaration part, and a command one.